# How to construct the header when a single key has multiple possible value?

Tags: python, header, web-crawler

Now I wish to scrape a web page with python and when I look into the header constructed by the web browser, there are several keys have multiple values:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.6
```

I wonder how should I construct the dictionary, `header`? Should I use

```
header = {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8', ...}
```

? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This would be wiser to separate the different values, hence use an array. You can do the following :

```
>>> accept = 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'
>>> header = {'Accept': accept.split(',')}
>>> header
{'Accept': ['text/html', 'application/xhtml+xml', 'application/xml;q=0.9', 'image/webp', '*/*;q=0.8']}
```

I used `split` to separate the comma-separated values, and have more visibility over them.